# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem regarding my update, if i have 1 row of data my update works but if I have 2 rows data, I got this problem.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 2 Primary

myController.php

```
public function update(Partner $partner) {
    $partner->update(array_except(Input::all(), '_token'));
}
```

Any idea whats the problem?

Comment: there's either a foreign key issue or a restraint somewhere AI'd column. You can also try `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html - Google the error, there are other possible reasons.

Comment: Would you post your migration file for partners? Could you also post your input array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the query to this

`public function UpdateItems(Item $updateitem, $item_id){
        $sname = Input::get('subcategory');
        $subname = ItemSubcategory::where('name',$sname)->first();
        $input = Input::except('_token');
        $updateitem->where('item_id', $item_id)
        ->update($input, ['subcategory' => $subname->id]);
}`

and now my code is working but i have a little problem.  All columns can be updated except for the `subcategory` column. Now my question is that is it possible to update the subcategory column together with the other columns using

```
update($input, ['subcategory' => $subname->id])
```

or is there any way to update the subcategory?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself. According to the documentation here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is **1** if the row is inserted as a new row, and **2** if an existing row is updated.

o when your query executes, if a new record is inserted it's ID is returned. If the record already exists then the existing record is updated. If no update is needed because the values all match then an ID is returned and the number of rows modified is 0. However, if the record is updated, the ID is returned and the number of rows modified is **2**. The keyholder is assuming two rows have been modified (even though only one has been) and is incorrectly returning the ID plus the next sequential ID (i.e. the ID plus 1).
[For example click here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/)

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution and its not proper but it worked. I just added another update query for the subcategory.

```
Item::whereItem_id($item_id)->update($input);
Item::whereItem_id($item_id)->update(['subcategory' => $subname->id]);
```